# Check if a fragment is within a specified area

Tags: opengl, shadows

Consider the following scene.
[image: Scene]

I transformed pMin and pMax from world space to viewport space. The area bound by pMin and pMax follows the users mouse sliding over the plane (larger rectangle).

Is there a way inside the fragment shader to decide if the fragment lies within the inner area or not? I tried comparing with gl_FragCoord.x and gl_FragCoord.z but it does not yield correct results.

```
if((gl_FragCoord.x < splitMax.x && gl_FragCoord.x > splitMin.x) 
&& (gl_FragCoord.z < splitMax.z && gl_FragCoord.z > splitMin.z)){
    //within area following the mouse
} else {
   //outside of area following the mouse
}
```

In cascaded shadow mapping, shadow maps are chosen based on the fragment's z value and whether it lies inside the computed frustum split z values. I'm trying to do the same only that I want my look up to also consider the x coordinate.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `gl_FragCoord.z` (the fragment's depth value [0,1]), and not `gl_FragCoord.y` (the fragment's y value [0.5, FRAME_HEIGHT-0.5])?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct coordinate system? In OpenGL it shall be `x` and `y` that aligns the direction of width and height of your screen, and `z` is the depth value./

Comment: I'm trying to move the inner rectangle over a plane that has [0,1,0] as its up vector. So yes I want to use    z to move it towards and away from the viewer.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to have but inside the fragment shader (because of shadow map lookups later on). http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/images/zones.png

Which space should I do this in? I haven't tried unprojecting the window coordinates inside the fragment shader.

I did the following with pMaxWorld:
`pMaxPerspectiveSpace = proj * view * pMax`
`pMaxNDC = pMax/pMax.w`
`vp = viewport`
`pMaxWindowSpace.x = (vp.w * pMaxNDC.x)/2 + (vp.x+vp.w)/2`

Comment: I did a similar thing some time ago, although my problem was a bit different, i moved away from using gl_FragCoord and rendered an Alpha map to a texture, then sampled from that texture and if the Alpha was below a certain threshold i discarded the fragment. This allows for more complex shapes.

Comment: Do you have some more info on that? Any sources?
I'm trying to base the decision which shadow map to access based on the fragment's x,z position.

Comment: What the heck is viewport space? Do you mean screen / window space?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant window space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a guy in ##opengl on freenode, I managed to get this working the following way:

**vertex shader**: Transform the incoming vertex to world space

```
out vec4 worldPos;
...
worldPos = modelMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
```

**fragment shader**: Send in pMin and pMax in world space coordinates

```
in vec3 pMin, pMax;
in vec4 worldPos;
...
if((worldPos.x > pMin.x && worldPos.x < pMax.x) && (worldPos.z > pMin.z && worldPos.z < pMax.z)){
   FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} else {
   FragColor is scene lighting
}
```

Result:
[image: result]